# What suits better for the following sentence? (Views or Sights)

Tags: word-choice, nouns

> - We didn't have time to visit many of the tourist _____ of the city.

a. views
 b. sights

---

Note: I was asked to choose one of the above options.

Comment: @Cardinal sorry but those are the only multi-choices given to us. so we have to choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you page through a [dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sight_1), you will see:

> [sights [plural]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sight_1#sight_1__18): the interesting places, especially in a town or a city

Therefore, you can choose the option **b**.

---

However, in terms of the option **a**, the [dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/view_1) will say that:

1. [countable] a personal opinion, belief, or attitude about a particular situation or subject

   > **1.1** [singular] a particular way of thinking about something
2. [countable/uncountable] the ability to see something from a particular place
3. [countable] a picture or photograph of a place, especially an attractive place